# Entity framework error when updating proc "the stored procedure returns no columns"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure with dynamic columns. When I update the stored procedure in Entity Framework I am getting an error

> The stored procedure returns no columns

I searched in google and I was added `SET FMTONLY OFF` in my stored procedure, but still I'm not getting the columns in Entity Framework.

My query is like this:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) 
;WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY #ResourceUtilization.[DAY] 
ORDER BY #ResourceUtilization.[DAY]) AS rowNbr, 
#ResourceUtilization.[DAY] 
FROM #ResourceUtilization ) 
SELECT @cols=STUFF ( ( SELECT ',' +QUOTENAME([DAY]) 
                       FROM CTE 
                       WHERE CTE.rowNbr=1 FOR XML PATH('') ) ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
DEPT_NAME,
EMP_NAME,
DESIGNATION,' + @cols +' 

FROM
(
    SELECT
        RU.DEPT_NAME,
        RU.EMP_NAME,
        RU.DESIGNATION,
        RU.[DAY],
        (
            CAST(RU.FIRST_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'',''+
            CAST(RU.SECOND_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'',''+
            CAST(RU.THIRD_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'',''+
            CAST(RU.GENERAL_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))
        ) AS SHIFT
    FROM
        #ResourceUtilization RU
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SHIFT) FOR [DAY] IN('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: How do you plan to pass `@cols` to your query? Where is declaration of `@cols`?

Comment: DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY #ResourceUtilization.[DAY] ORDER BY #ResourceUtilization.[DAY]) AS rowNbr,
        #ResourceUtilization.[DAY]
    FROM
        #ResourceUtilization
)
SELECT @cols=STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' +QUOTENAME([DAY])
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.rowNbr=1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,1,'')

Comment: You can print your query before executing and analyze it.

Comment: How is Entity Framework supposed to map the results of this stored procedure when the shape of the response changes every time you execute it? This is a horribly bad design - don't do stuff like that! One stored procedure should do **one thing and one thing only** and should return a well-defined, fixed shape of data.

Comment: Hi, What you said is right, but how to create a proc. please tell me.